# Accessing Windows 7 from Ubuntu on a network

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, networking, file-sharing

What is the simplest way to access shared folders on Windows 7 system from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

You could get the `smbclient` and access the shared network with `smb://`.
Also look at [SMB4K](http://smb4k.berlios.de/).

Answer (score 1):

depends what you mean by simple using a filezilla to access ubuntu via ssh/scp is pretty simple.

If you want something more permanent you probably want to set up samba - I think this can be done via the gui in ubuntu now.